# Best file type to save budget data in Java?

Tags: java, save, finance

I'm starting on a new budgeting/allowance project and I'm trying to figure out how to save the data between opening and closing the program.  Arrays seem clunky and I don't know how I would save the array data to a file anyway. I've really only worked with text files before so this is new to me.

I'm assuming a database of some sort is what I need but I don't know what I should be looking for.

I know this has to be a simple issue but I honestly don't know where to start; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about *a database*?

Comment: Thanks for the response :)

I was thinking a database of some sort would probably be the best thing to use but I wasn't sure if there were other options. I wasn't sure if there was possibly a more simple solution that I was overlooking.

I'm used to working in Excel so Java is a little overwhelming sometimes and I just feel lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is entirely for you to decide, there is no one right answer here.

You can save in a text file, e.g. CSV if very simple, otherwise JSON or XML are common choices, or in a binary file, e.g. Java serialized objects, or some embedded database file might do.

It really depends on how complex the data is, how big the file can become, whether you want to be able to edit the file directly in a text editor, and how important load/save performance is to you.

Since it's a new project and you seem fairly new to this, I'd suggest JSON or XML, whichever of the two you are more familiar with. But that's just my opinion.

It's entirely your choice.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! There were just so many options I wasn't even sure where to start. I'll look into the options you listed and see what I think will work for best for the project. Thanks again. :)